# Auto-accept incoming bluetooth tether request?

Tags: bluetooth-tethering

Everytime I tether my PC to use my phone's internet via bluetooth it (phone) asks for confirmation. Is there a way to auto-accept that confirmation or suppress it altogether?

---

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.refluxa.android.bac&feature=more_from_developer&rdid=de.refluxa.android.bac&rdot=1) doesn't work for me. (I'm not sure whether it's its intended purpose. Although it could be and it might be not working on *my* device... (I've sent email to the dev.))

I can't find any other apps...

Comment: Didn't you mean [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.refluxa.android.bat) from the same developer?

Comment: @ce4 No, that one just enables "bluetooth tethering" option from the settings. (it's disabled by default upon every boot). Which is actually fine by me; I can manually enable it when I want. What I would rather have is it ***auto-accept*** the incoming connection request from my PC.

Comment: I think that confirmation request is specific to your phone's firmware (my Galaxy Nexus doesn't do that , it's running CyanogenMod 10.1 aka Android 4.2.2)

Comment: @ce4 Did you install the app? (or is that by default?)

Comment: Yes, the one I linked is all I need with CyanogenMod, but note: there had never been aa confirmation request upon connecting. Without the app, I needed zo enable Bluetooth tethering after each reboot